# Background-color isn't responsive

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie at this. I have a problem. I'm creating a personal page where I want a background-color in the top part of the page (covering a section) and I want another background-color in the middle of the page (covering another section).
The thing is that I did that but when I go to developer tools the design it doesn't responsive. My body background kinda "creates" a margin aside my second background.
I don't know if I'm explain it well but here is my code and the bug that I have:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Fredoka', sans-serif;
    margin: 0%;
    padding: 0%;
}

body {
    background-color: #3a5056;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.middle {
    background-color: white;
    height: 1866px;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-top: 230px;
}

.cards-list {
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.card {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25), -5px -5px 30px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.card .card_image {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.card .card_image img {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    border-radius: 40px;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card .card_title {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 40px 40px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: -80px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #2c3d42;
}
section .intro {
    height: 40px;
    width: 850px;
    padding: 6%;
}

.intro {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    align-self: center;
    min-width: 850px;
}

.intro:nth-child() {
    align-self: center;
}

.abt-me {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 250px;
    padding: 1%;
    color: #2c3d42;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    margin-top: -2550px;
    border: 1px hidden;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 30px 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 17px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 17px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.text-box {
    padding: 1%;
    margin-top: -8px;
    font-size: 21px;
    width: 750px;
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fredoka:wght@300;400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="main">
        <div id="name">
            <h1>Hello, I'm <span id="me">Sapph</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div id="scroll">
            <section id="section02" class="demo">
                <a href="#cards"><span></span></a>
            </section>
        </div>
        <nav class="social">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Twitter <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="">Github <i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="">Linkedin <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
    <section class="middle">
        <div id="cards">
            <div class="cards-list">
                <div class="card 1">
                    <div class="card_image"></div>
                    <div class="card_title title-white">
                        <p>Contact</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card 3">
                    <div class="card_image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card_title">
                        <p>Projects</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="abt-me">
            <h2 style="margin-bottom: 12px" ;><b>
                About Me</b>
            </h2>
            <div class="text-box">
                <p>
                    <center>Hello, I'm...</center>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <footer>&copy Copyright</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my problem: https://prnt.sc/w4Zkw0QU7P67

This is what I need: https://prnt.sc/UhNmn4djohPS

I took the photos in the developer tools. Thanks

Comment: You might want to also include the HTML.

Comment: Done. I edit to add the HTML code, thanks

Comment: Your style works for me at Chrom and Edge browsers. there is not difference in Developer mode up to screen width 100px. Comment you style.css and check again I used bootstrap version 5.1 with your codes. <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

Comment: @Mehrwarz Thanks for comment, I realized that when I have width: 890 or less than that the white background (of middle section) ends and I have the problem. It's a media querie thing? or is something wrong with the css code?

Comment: can you share your CSS code for #cards, .card, .clard-list, and .card_image? in the page.

Comment: @Mehrwarz Done. I edited the code on the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find the @media section for max-width:890px in your style.css and edit the "section" tag style. or past the below code on your page, this should help. It is the amount of padding added on the section for screen width less than 890px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 890px) {
    section{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

If you want to change the section style for all screen widths just use:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 1360px) {
    section{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but I have to do that with all width in media queries? because it works for 890px but less than that I have the same that before

Comment: Just remove the @media and past the section block it works for all status. " section{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 10px;
    }"

Comment: It doesn't work at all, I already have a section block but it's for my .intro class. That could be the problem?

Comment: Use the defined min and max media size. @media only screen and (min-width: 360px) and (max-width: 1360px). i edited.

Comment: Thank you so much for help me. I did that and then I thought about write in body, html block margin 0 padding 0 and overflow-x: hidden, and it worked. Thank you so much